# How to check a input field that it contains only numeric or special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a input field where user can input their name i want when user enter name then with the help of javascript we can check that name not contains only numeric value or only special character value without any alphabet,when he move to next section.i want we show a popup that name is invalid and focus on same input.how to do it with the help of jquery can anyone explain.
i found correct regular expression to do this.

```
var regex = /^[0-9~!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g
```

then check your input field value with this expression .test method,it either true or false based on value.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: what you have tried so far ? SO is not for writing a code for you.. -_-

Comment: @thecor i dont know much please explain with code

Comment: SO isn't here to write code for you. Learn to research for yourself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. Even typing the title of this question in to google gets you several links to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one validation using regular expression for allow numeric value ,alphabetic andspecial characters.

((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])
```

Comment: i want to allow numeric special and alphabet but not only numeric or special char

Comment: numeric , special and alphabet three  are compulsary for enter name?